# How to install mapnik python3 wrapper in conda?

Tags: python, conda, mapnik

I have installed mapnik 3.0.12 with `conda install -c mrterry mapnik`, but why I can`t import it in my code?

```py
import mapnik
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mapnik'`

I looked in `anaconda3/pkgs/mapnik-3.0.12-0/lib` and there is no `python3.7` folder there, only .so and .a files.

I have installed mapnik with `sudo apt install python3-mapnik` in ubuntu 18.04 and it imports well with `/usr/bin/python3` interpreter. And in directory `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mapnik`  there is some .py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tool, but it looks like Mapnik is a C++ library that has separate Python bindings.  You need to install both `mapnik` and `python-mapnik`.  Only Python 2 is supported, so you need to create a new env for this.

### Conda (only if you trust the channel)

[A search of Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=mapnik) shows only **linux-64** platform is available and only from user channels. I'm following your lead on using the **mrterry** channel, but generally I will only use a channel if I trust the user/org.

```
conda create -n myenv -c mrterry python=2.7 mapnik python-mapnik
```

### Recommended Approach

Since I don't recognize any of the channels in the search, personally I would just follow [the official install instructions](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Mapnik-Installation).  First, I would set up a Conda env with Python 2.7 and [the dependencies that Mapnik lists](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/INSTALL.md#depends).  Then activate that env, and proceed with following the instructions (`./configure`, `make`, etc.).